# Angular 2 - What is a DI error?

Tags: angular

I'm having an error when I import a service, but I have no idea why

```
import { CDService } from "../../services/definition";

constructor(
    private toastyCommunicationService: ToastyCommunicationService,
    private CDService : CDService,
    private SharedService: SharedService,
    private DatePipe: DatePipe
) { }
```

I have made my service litteraly empty because I was so frustrated with the error and not knowing what was causing it.

```
export class CDService {

}
```

Now I receive the **error**

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
Error: DI Error
```

I have 2 questions:

**1)** What the hell is a DI error?

**2)** How can I solve this error?

Comment: It's Dependency injection error. Please, post more code.

Comment: @IgorJanković which code? which dependencies can it need? there is not a single line of code in the service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is dependency injection error. I think you are missing @Injectable() decorator:

```
@Injectable() // this line
export class CDService {

}
```

Edit:

Have you added CDService into NgModule?

Comment: Have you added CDService into NgModule?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you added this service to your module's `providers`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your service is injectable by using `@Injectable()`. This way angular understands its not only a typesscript class but its a angular service.

Comment: there are other ways but to start with this is the best way